# Trying to get Property of Non Object for PHP

Tags: php, sql, user-input

I am new at PHP and continue to get the "Trying to get property of non object" error. My goal is to allow user to type in a customer id and for it to return that particular customer's info. My code is below and is all in one PHP file. The error states that I am getting a error on line 34 (the line that has `"while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {"`).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <Head>
    </Head>
<Body>
    <style> table, TH {width: 500px; height: 20px;} </style>
    <form action="php.php" method="post">
    Customer ID: <input type="text" name="customerid"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['customerid'])) {
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "test";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "test";
            $cust = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customerid']);

            // Create connection
            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

            // Check connection
                    if (!$conn) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                    }
                    echo "<Table>". "<TH>Customer Name</TH>"."<TH>barr</TH>"."<TH>Cusomter Id</TH></Table>";
                    $sql = "SELECT customer_name, barr, customer_id FROM churn.data WHERE customer_id =". $cust ."";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        echo "<Table><TH>". $row["customer_name"]. "</TH><TH>". $row["barr"]."</TH><TH>". $row["customer_id"]."</TH></Table>";
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "0 results";
                    }
            mysqli_close($conn);
        }   
    ?>  
</body>
</html>
```

I changed some info because I was concerned about privacy so hopefully that doesn't affect anything.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you print_r($row)?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code instead of while loop.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 

echo "<Table><TH>". $row["customer_name"]. "</TH><TH>". $row["barr"]."</TH><TH>". $row["customer_id"]."</TH></Table>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated the doc to what you said and got the same error on the exact same line but now the line is the
echo "<Table><TH>". $row["customer_name"]. "</TH><TH>". $row["barr"]."</TH><TH>". $row["customer_id"]."</TH></Table>";

Comment: Sorry, I didn't finish my response in the time I had to edit. As I was saying

Thanks for the response. I updated the doc to what you said and got the same error on the same line 35 but now line 35 is

echo "<Table><TH>". $row["customer_name"]. "</TH><TH>". $row["barr"]."</TH><TH>". $row["customer_id"]."</TH></Table>";

Even if I add a space so that line 35 is blank I get the same error.